# Culturing Yeast and Bacteria from Pulque

Tags: yeast

I'm interested in making pulque, and was wondering how to go about culturing the yeast and bacteria necessary for making it from an existing batch.

Is this at all dangerous? I know doing this with yeast from beer is common, I'm only worried about the bacteria part.

What are best practices for reducing the chance of infection and ensuring a good batch?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

In April  2015 I broke or 'quiebre' a maguey to harvest its nectar, aguamiel, and I knew that I could make pulque from it, first time i tried to do this stuff.
Well, i just took a sip of my own made pulque, and it tasted good. Let me share what little I know.

One must harvest it right before the maguey shoot come out, ( 8-9yrs old maguey ) or if it just came out, like mine, mine had already reached about 3-4 feet when I found out and chopped it  and carved its center, where the sap gathers. ONe must cut out the maguey during full moon to 1/4 waning moon. it took me paciently to carve it for two weeks before the nectar started pooling in. patience. one carves it twice daily carving out about a hand full each time. Once the honeywater comes out, one can collect it three times a day if the days are hot, else two times a day, this way it won't start to ferment. But one must carve out that hand full each time one collects the honeywater.
Am just starting about making pulque, and started asking my old relatives from Mexico about how to make pulque and molasess from aguamiel (honewater).

Now about pulque, I asked my cousin to bring me a liter of pulq from a restaurant in CHula Vista Califronia, i let it age and from there I started my own base. For the one liter after ageing, one week, I removed the excess foam and used a new clean glass container, and added about a 1/4 liter honeywater and next day I added 1/4 liter again, I then left it alone for about three days, removing the foam every time, then drank a portion, and replenished it with new honeywater. that is where I am.

Now looking at the Mexican maguey farmers in youtube, 'tlachiqueros', one mentioned that to start your pulque base  one must let for example, 1 liter of honeywater ferment for a whole month, then change it to a clean container, but don't use soap stuff to wash it, but use lemon juice and a natural loofah type or bristle. Then to that 1 liter add about a 1/5 of honeywater daily
( I can't remember how often ), then when that pulque has become  enough and you want to start drinking it then one must add 1 liter of aguamiel per 2 liters of pulque. or two to one ration. Remember to transfer the pulque to a clean container daily.No soaps.
I hope this helps. GOod luck and don't give up. Drink of the Aztecs.

One warning, the honeywater causes a skin type irritation that itches like hell for several minutes. Specially the leaves zap. wear long rubber gloves.

my email  rigo.deleon7@gmail.com

thank you.